# TabError в коде для Discord Бота

Tags: python, бот, discord

Хочу сделать код для дискорд бота на моём проекте. Сделал всё правильно но выдается ошибка Tab Error:inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Вот мой код:
P.S Я не ввел токен специально

````py
import random

import discord

from discord.ext import commands


move = ['!move']
cake = ['!cake']


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')


@client.event


async def on_message(message):

    msg = message.content.lower()
    
    rand = random.randrange(3, 13)
    
    if msg in move:
        work_timer = {}

        if message.content.startswith('!move'):
            try:
                work_time = work_timer[message.author.id]
                work_timer[message.author.id] = time.time()
                if work_timer[message.author.id] - work_time <= 60:
                    await client.send_message(message.channel, "Ты сможешь использовать эту команду через 1 минуту")
                    return
                else:
                    if rand == 3:
                        await message.channel.send('Вы смогли переместиться на' + ' ' + str(rand) + ' ' + 'клеток вперёд! Но вы потеряли 9 единиц голода.')
                    if rand == 4:
                        await message.channel.send('Вы смогли переместиться на' + ' ' + str(rand) + ' ' + 'клеток вперёд! Но вы потеряли 12 единиц голода.')
                    if rand == 5:
                        await message.channel.send('Вы смогли переместиться на' + ' ' + str(rand) + ' ' + 'клеток вперёд! Но вы потеряли 15 единиц голода.')
                    if rand == 6:
                        await message.channel.send('Вы смогли переместиться на' + ' ' + str(rand) + ' ' + 'клеток вперёд! Но вы потеряли 18 единиц голода.')
                    if rand == 7:
                        await message.channel.send('Вы смогли переместиться на' + ' ' + str(rand) + ' ' + 'клеток вперёд! Но вы потеряли 21 единиц голода.')
                    if rand == 8:
                        await message.channel.send('Вы смогли переместиться на' + ' ' + str(rand) + ' ' + 'клеток вперёд! Но вы потеряли 24 единиц голода.')
                    if rand == 9:
                        await message.channel.send('Вы смогли переместиться на' + ' ' + str(rand) + ' ' + 'клеток вперёд! Но вы потеряли 27 единиц голода.')
                    if rand == 10:
                        await message.channel.send('Вы смогли переместиться на' + ' ' + str(rand) + ' ' + 'клеток вперёд! Но вы потеряли 30 единиц голода.')
                    if rand == 11:
                        await message.channel.send('Вы смогли переместиться на' + ' ' + str(rand) + ' ' + 'клеток вперёд! Но вы потеряли 33 единиц голода.')
                    if rand == 12:
                        await message.channel.send('Вы смогли переместиться на' + ' ' + str(rand) + ' ' + 'клеток вперёд! Но вы потеряли 36 единиц голода.')
                    if rand == 13:
                        await message.channel.send('Вы смогли переместиться на' + ' ' + str(rand) + ' ' + 'клеток вперёд! Но вы потеряли 39 единиц голода.')
@client.event
async def on_message2(message):
    msg = message.content.lower()
    if msg in cake:
        await message.channel.send('С днём рождения Шниленд! Вам выдан бесплатный приз в виде 10 единиц Голода')```



Ошибка:


C:\Users\77715>"C:\Users\77715\Desktop\Discord Bot\bot.py"
  File "C:\Users\77715\Desktop\Discord Bot\bot.py", line 19
    try:
       ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
````

Comment: А где `except:` соответствующий `try:`?

Comment: CrazyElf А где его надо вставить чтобы ошибка пропала?

Comment: Написал отдельный ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы исчезла ошибка для начала можно добавить `except: pass` на том же уровне, что `try:`:

```
        try:
            work_time = work_timer[message.author.id]
            # ... я тут пропустил строки для наглядности
                if rand == 13:
                    await message.channel.send('Вы смогли переместиться на' + ' ' + str(rand) + ' ' + 'клеток вперёд! Но вы потеряли 39 единиц голода.')
        except:
            pass
```

Но хорошо бы если бы вы знали зачем вам нужен `try/except`, что вы хотите делать в случае возникновения исключения.